# How to preselect capslock in TouchKeyboard component

Tags: delphi, keyboard, capslock

I am working with Delphi TTouchKeyboard component. Because in later use people will mainly use capital letters, I would like to preselect capslock.
My problem now is, that the Touchkeyboard only changes its key caption when I click directly on a key. If the state is toggled by an (external) keydown message, one can use capital letters, but the keyboard component will still dislpay small letters on the keys. How could I solve that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the only work arround is to edit the original source code.

http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88770 (I haven't tested it)

I've tried to write a patch with this code but with out any luck because I can not acces the private field Fbuttons.

So if you want this you'll have to patch the original code